# Extract specific portion of HTML file using c++/boost::regex

Tags: c++, regex, string, boost

I have a series of thousands of HTML files and for the ultimate purpose of running a word-frequency counter, I am only interested on a particular portion from each file. For example, suppose the following is part of one of the files:

```
<!-- Lots of HTML code up here -->
<div class="preview_content clearfix module_panel">
      <div class="textelement   "><div><div><p><em>"Portion of interest"</em></p></div>
</div>
<!-- Lots of HTML code down here -->
```

How should I go about using regular expressions in c++ (boost::regex) to extract that particular portion of text highlighted in the example and put that into a separate string?

I currently have some code that opens the html file and reads the entire content into a single string, but when I try to run a `boost::regex_match` looking for that particular beginning of line `<div class="preview_content clearfix module_panel">`, I don't get any matches. I'm open to any suggestions as long as it's on c++.

Comment: Obligatory reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1088

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all I needed was something quite simple (as per question above), I was able to get it done without using regex or any type of parsing. Following is the code snippet that did the trick:

```
    // Read HTML file into string variable str
    std::ifstream t("/path/inputFile.html");
    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    // Find the two "flags" that enclose the content I'm trying to extract
    size_t pos1 = str.find("<div class=\"preview_content clearfix module_panel\">");
    size_t pos2 = str.find("</em></p></div>");

    // Get that content and store into new string
    std::string buf = str.substr(pos1,pos2-pos1);
```

Thank you for pointing out the fact that I was totally on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I go about using regular expressions in c++ (boost::regex) to extract that particular portion of text highlighted in the example and put that into a separate string?

You don't.

Never use regular expressions to process HTML. Whether in C++ with Boost.Regex, in Perl, Python, JavaScript, *anything and anywhere*. HTML is not a regular language; therefore, it cannot be processed in any meaningful way via regular expressions. Oh, in extremely limited cases, you *might* be able to get it to extract some particular information. But once those cases change, you'll find yourself unable to get done what you need to get done.

I would suggest using an actual HTML parser, like [LibXML2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) (which does have the ability to read HTML4). But using regex's to parse HTML is simply using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Yeah, after doing some more reading I now see that it seems like a bad idea to use regex when dealing with html. Thanks for pointing that out. Given that that is the only thing I want to do (i.e., get the content of that specific tag), what would you suggest I use? I've been looking around but most things I come across seem like a bit of an overkill.